# Let $f:G \rightarrow G'$ be a homomorphism. Let $a \in G$ be such that $o(a)=n$ and $o(f(a))=m$. Show that $f$ is one-one iff $m=n$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

> Let $f:G \rightarrow G'$ be a homomorphism. Let $a \in G$ be such that $o(a)=n$ and $o(f(a))=m$. Show that $f$ is one-one iff $m=n$

I know that $m|n$ and can prove that $n|m$ which implies that $m=n$. But how to prove converse?

One more doubt:

> Why do we need to prove converse when there is an "iff" in the statement?

**Edit:** Here $o(a)$ means order of 'a'.

Comment: Is there anything you're missing? If $ a=e$, and $f=e$ (a valid homomorphism), then $n=m=1$ yet, the function is neither injective nor surjective. ($G$ any non triv group)

Comment: @mdave16 sorry but I couldn't understand.

Comment: You gave a statement (in question). I then gave you a counter example to your statement. This means the statement in your question is incomplete or incorrect. Or did you not understand (1) my counterexample or (2) why it is a counter example or (3) something about the statement?

Comment: (2) if $a=e$ , $f(a)=e' \implies f(a)=f(e) \implies a=e$, so this is one-one

Comment: Can we stick to using injective? And $f$ as a whole is not. E.g. Let $G=C_2={e,g}$ And $f$ an homom. to itself. Then $f(g)=e$ too. I think perhaps the statement you wanted was for $m=n$ for all $a \in G$.(also, tag me to get a faster reply :P)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement of your problem is a little confusing.  Is this what you want to say?

> Let $f: G \rightarrow G'$ be a group homomorphism.  For each $a \in G$, let $n_a$ be the order of $a$, and let $m_a$ be the order of $f(a)$.  Then $f$ is one to one if and only if for every $a \in G$, we have $n_a = m_a$.

For your second question, "Why do we need to prove the converse when there is an iff in the statement?"  An 'if and only if' is way of writing down two statements at once.  That is, you are supposed to prove

> (1) If $f$ is one to one, then for every $a \in G$, we have $n_a = m_a$

and

> (2) If for every $a \in G$, we have $n_a = m_a$, then $f$ is one to one.

So you are definitely going to need to prove the converse of something when you are asked to prove an if and only if.  The statements (1) and (2) are converses of each other.

Comment: It seems much easier to prove (2'): If $f$ is not injective, then $na \ne m_a$ for some $a \in G$.

Comment: I initially thought that was the correct statement, but wanted OP to correct it themselves.

Comment: @mdave16 yes the problem statement should have "for every $a \in G"$.